# Application of Poisson distribution to image processing

Tags: poisson-distribution, image-processing

I'm trying to write a program to detect water bubbles in heated oil. I've applied a canny edge detection filter to the image and the results look like the following:

No bubbles: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/nobubbles.png/ Bubbles: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/35/swirlsg.png/

I'm trying to find a way to determine when the bubbles are present.

Would it be appropriate to check if the white pixels are Poisson distributed?

Comment: Both images show too much spatial association for either to be purely random (there's a clear boundary in both). What summary of or information from the images exactly would you be testing for being Poisson? Is it that you mean 'test if the white pixels are uniformly distributed'? If so, that's what the first part of my response relates to. However, if you move away from a test of randomness to a measure of association (/measure of randomness), that may be a good discriminator between the two types of image, even though both might be rejected, one might tend to be more extreme.

Comment: The most obvious feature is those small vaguely circular sturctures, that come close to closing but don't quite. One presumes those that the actual bubbles. It seems like they'd be the obvious feature to try to make something that's sensitive to, but I am sure there are people better placed that I am to make suggestions for that.

Comment: 'those small vaguely circular structures' are indeed the bubbles.

I was thinking of dividing the image up into partitions and counting the number of pixels in each partition. then use Pearson's chi squared test to measure how well the data fits a Poisson distribution

Comment: Okay, so two issues: 1) you'll have lots of tests- do you have a plan to deal with that?  and  2) consider trying the statistic itself rather than a formal hypothesis test.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by 'lots of tests'

Comment: Ah, it's okay, I think I misinterpreted what you were saying ... but now if I understand you right, aren't you dealing with a binomial rather than a Poisson?

Comment: hmmm ... well the Poisson distribution "expresses the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval [of space]" --  wikipedia. 
The binomial distribution models the probability of a certain number of successes given a certain number of trials. I think the Poisson distribution can be derived from the Binomial, as the limiting case as the number of trials go to infinity. I might choose another probability distribution instead of Poisson. I'll be sure to give the binomial a try as well, Thanks :)

Comment: The images are no longer available, could you post examples an inline images? I think it is worth it because it is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the solution that ended up working for me was to do a gaussian smoothing filter of the image before doing the canny edge detection. This eliminated much of the noise so that the canny edge detection filter only detected bubble edges. This is much simpiler than having to create eigen bubbles then use FFT. The simpiler technique worked very well for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Knowing what has worked is not the same as finding what works for you.

Comment: fyi: http://phys.org/news/2013-05-secret-mathematicians-evolution-dissolution-clusters.html

Answer (score 2):

If this was something that I had to get done, and I once had to get done something similar, I would go a totally different direction.  I would take a "characteristic bubble" and use it as a "image-let" then use frequency domain methods to determine locations of candidate bubbles in the field.  It avoids all this "edge" complexity and can give you the bubble location accurate to substantially less than a pixel.

Here is a thesis on the subject.  ([link](http://repository.asu.edu/items/15110))  It is not a bad start and gives a useful 1d "toy problem" with which you can refine your methods before going to higher dimensions.  It also shows application to bubble tracking in 2d but that is toward the end and rests heavily on the 1d staging.  Please check out the bibliography including Adrian and Reed.  You can also consider the tool "[PIV Sleuth](http://ltcf.tam.uiuc.edu/downloads/Software/PIVSleuth/PIVSleuthManual.pdf)" [here](http://ltcf.tam.uiuc.edu/downloads.html).  Particle Image Velocimetry (PIV) might be a good subject to explore here.

Comment: There's alot of information to absorb here. What's a characteristic bubble? Also What is an 'image-let'? Is this like a wavelet? Is this method similar to the use of eigenfaces in face recognition?
What are frequency domain methods? Do you mean like fourier analysis? How can this be adapted for image recognition?

Comment: A characteristic bubble means a bubble that is characteristic of the field of bubbles.  It is an image of a bubble that is generic enough that all bubbles going through your field of view are adequately described by it.  Image-let is my own nomenclature.  It is like a wavelet in the sense of how it is used, but not how it is derived.  Wavelets have to obey some rules that these image templates do not.  This makes a platform/framework for detection that can be very flexible.  It is very much like an eigenface, but you just need one.  I mean ifft2(fft2(a)./fft2(b)) .. deconv2d + interp.

Comment: is a the initial image? is b the characteristic bubble? is interp interpolation? What do I do with these?

Comment: limited character length in comments.  Maybe I should edit the answer.  So you find a single good bubble image, call it "A".  It helps if it is small.  Then you take whatever you are measuring, an image of the field, call it "B".  It is good to get your initial settings from a static image, but they work well in motion after they are set.  When you convolute in 2d the images and then de-convolute their dot product, the result has very quadratic peaks at locations of 'bubble' in the image.  ifft2(fft2(A).*fft2(B)).  Knowing that it is quadratic allows you to do interpolation near the peak and .

Comment: I think you got cut off there. 
Could you explicitly give me the equation?
Also in the line ifft2(fft2(A).*fft2(B)), does '.*' mean dot product? convolution? something else?

Comment: I think I might understand a little better now, you are using the convolution theorem.

Comment: in order to dot product fft2(A) and fft2(B), they need to be the same dimension, this seems unlikely to be the case.
Also, I'm not sure how interpolation fits into this.

Comment: zero pad the "characteristic" bubble.  Also zero pad the image itself.  This avoids "Gibbs effect" and makes arrays the same size.

Comment: After you have result, the interpolation gets you to sub-pixel. If you want to detect IF there are bubbles then interpolation doesn't help.  Interpolation is required for Sub-Pixel measurement of WHERE the bubbbles are.

Comment: I would make your C=ifft2(fft2(A).*fft2(B)) or conv2(A,B) to get your   convolution peak.  Next I would use a known bubble-present image and a known bubble absent image to determine a threshold in the "C", a control limit, that when breached indicates presence of one or more bubbles and when below that value indicates a lack of bubbles.